# BlackBerry setTitle text alignment

Tags: blackberry, alignment

How can I align the setTitle text to right/left?

Thanks

Comment: +1 because it is a valid question about MainScreen.setTitle()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
RichTextField rtf1 = new RichTextField("Right-aligned plain", RichTextField.TEXT_ALIGN_RIGHT);
RichTextField rtf2 = new RichTextField("Centered extra bold", RichTextField.TEXT_ALIGN_HCENTER);
RichTextField rtf3 = new RichTextField("Left-aligned italic", RichTextField.TEXT_ALIGN_LEFT);
```

From [this](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Read_only_text_field_1211032_11.jsp) post.

Or [this](http://blackberry-tips-bikas.blogspot.com/2009/07/write-title-bar-in-blackberry.html) post...

Comment: Thanks but if I use this solution, the title disappears after I scroll through the Screen.

Comment: add a VerticalFieldManager, put a style of "scrolling" in its constructor and then add the content to this manager not to the screen, this will make the title non-scrollable with the remaining content